# Upgrading `popt` requires to upgrade too many packages

Tags: rhel, rpm, syslog-ng

I am currently in the process of upgrading `syslog-ng` using `rpm`.
In the upgrade process, I found out that `syslog-ng` has a dependency with `rpm-libs` which have a dependency with `popt`. The dependency tree to `popt` is large and deep. Upgrading `popt` and `rpm-libs` would require upgrading a lot of packages.
We do not want to upgrade too much packages because this is a production server and we do not want to have any impacts.

Is there a simple way to upgrage `syslog-ng` without upgradings a lot of packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If syslog-ng is requiring a new version of rpm-libs, then it sounds like syslog-ng was built with rpmbuild, librpmbuild, etc which was compiled from newer source than than the "rpm-libs" package that is installed on your production server.

If you have the source to rpm-libs, rpm, rpmbuild, etc that is installed on your server, then you should try to compile rpmbuild and use the resulting rpmbuild binary to create your new syslog-ng RPM.

I wouldn't call that "simple", but if you don't want to update a bunch of other packages, then you don't have many options.

I would NOT recommend force updating or nodeps updating.